# Sort shopping list based on previous shopping trips

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science

**I want to sort a shopping list based on the order items were checked off in previous shopping trips.** For example I go to the store and shop Apples, Bananas and Eggs.

Next I go to the store I shop Avocados and Tomatos and Apples. For my next trip the application sorts Avocados, Tomatos and Apples all before Eggs f.e.

I found this post talking about topological sorting: [How to sort a shopping list based on previous pick order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310576/how-to-sort-a-shopping-list-based-on-previous-pick-order).

However I am not sure how this should work since in theory **I could have cycles** (A user could theoretically check off apples and then bananas and the next time bananas are checked off before apples).

Could you guide me on how to tackle this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: If there are no cycles, then you're looking for a **topological sort** of a directed graph. If there are cycles, then there doesn't exist an "perfect" shopping order given the previous shopping lists. I.e., there doesn't exist a topological sort of this graph. So instead, you'd be looking for a "best" order. If you search for "best topological search in graph with cycles", you will find papers about the [feedback vertex set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set) and other "similar" problems. See for instance this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17148103/3080723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assume:**

1. Past item orderings should guide ordering the current order.
2. Any new items appear after any items ordered historically.
3. Orderings further back in time should have less impact than more recent orderings.

**My idea** is to assign weights to items seen in past orders based on:

1. Their position in a historic ordering.
2. How old that odering is.

The weightings might need adjusting, but, using data from that other question you link to, the **Python code below** does create orderings based on historic orderings:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

shop = [['Toothpaste', 'Bread', 'Meat', 'Vegetables', 'Milk', 'Ice cream'],      # last
        ['CDs', 'Bread', 'Fruit', 'Vegetables', 'Juice', 'Sugar', 'Chocolates'], # last-but-1
        ['Meat', 'Juice', 'Milk', 'Sugar']]  # last-but-2

def weight_from_index(idx: int) -> float | int:
    "Items to the left are of LOwer wt and will sort first."
    return idx + 1

def historic_multiplier(idy: int) -> float:
    "Older rows have larger multipliers and so are of lower overall weight."
    return (idy + 1)**1

def shopping_weights(history: list[list[str]]) -> dict[str, int | float]:
    "Weight for items from historic shops."
    item2weight = defaultdict(float)
    for y, hist in enumerate(history):
        for x, item in enumerate(hist):
            item2weight[item] += historic_multiplier(y) * weight_from_index(x)
    return dict(item2weight)

def order_items(items: list[str], weights) -> list[str]:
    wts = weights.copy()
    new_items = set(items) - set(wts)

    # New items last, but in given order otherwise
    max_wt = max(wts.values())
    for itm in new_items:
        wts[itm] = max_wt + 1 + items.index(itm)

    return sorted(items, key = lambda i: wts[i])


item_weights = shopping_weights(shop)
new_shop = ['Curry', 'Vegetables', 'Eggs', 'Milk', 'CDs', 'Meat']

new_order = order_items(new_shop, item_weights)
print(new_order)
# ['CDs', 'Meat', 'Vegetables', 'Milk', 'Curry', 'Eggs']


# Update the historic item orders
shop.insert(0, new_order)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Just wanted to let you know that i saw your answer and really appreciate it. I'll review your answer tomorrow and check whether I understand what is going on and whether it solves my problem. I already upvoted and will make sure to accept the answer if it happens to be a solution i can proceed with.